# Get-ChildItem on Powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to list out all directories and their sub directories on the network share. Issue I am facing is the roots1.txt file has just network folders for example \\xxxx and not \\xxxx\xx and i need the list of subfolders in \\xxxx 
This code works when i use it with \\xxxx\xx but when I try it with \\xxxx it gives the error

> get-childitem : Cannot find path '\\' because it does not exist.

```
 $RootPath = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\roots1.txt"
$hash = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse -force |
  Group-Object directoryname -AsHashTable -AsString

$hash.GetEnumerator() | 
  ForEach-Object { [PSCustomobject]@{Path = $_.value.fullname -join '|'}} |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\darpan.vedi\Desktop\paths.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `\\xxxx` is not a folder or share - it's a host, and you can't enumerate its contents like a normal folder.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is there any way to enumerate the folders present in the host?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer to the linked duplicate question

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I checked it, the issue I am facing is I do not have escalated privileges on the machine I want to run this script, I want to use something like Net View to create a CSV file. Can you tell me how would I do that as I am very new to powershell.